# Burndown chart after Sprint Planning

Tags: tfs, scrum, azure-devops

We just began using Visual Studio Online to help us manage our sprints.

Our sprint started today, the 27th Jan.  We had our Sprint Planning in the morning, where we committed backlog items to our sprint.

The burndown chart looked like this after Sprint Planning:

[image]

It must be confused because the sprint actually started before we began adding items.

**Is it not possible to specify a time for the sprint start?**

We cannot start it from tomorrow the 28th, because work would have begun after Sprint Planning on the 27th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is currently (as of jan 2014) not possible, but requested numerous times in the past. I've discussed the item personally with some of the Product Team members responsible for this feature and I know that they would like to change this to support what you're asking for at some point. I couldn't find an item on [uservoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/search?query=start%20sprint%20burn%20down) in a quick search. You might want to raise a request there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So, is the only solution to have Sprint Planning occur before the sprint?  This is a problem.

Comment: Yes, or at least have your tasks estimated before sprint planning ;). It's worse when you have you sprints end on a week-day.

Comment: Or learn to ignore the spike on the first day. In the end it won't kill you.

Comment: Don't forget: The idea of a Burndown Chart is *only* to show how much work remains at a point in time. Your chart is correctly reflecting that. As jessehouwing says, live with the spike on the graph.